# Counting keys in LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>

Tags: java

Let's say I have something like this:

```
LinkedHashMap <String, ArrayList<String>> h 
keyOne has
stringOne 
stringTwo 
stringThree

keyTwo has
stringOne
```

How do I count the size of ArrayList of the associated key? So for keyOne, it should give me 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just write `h.get(key).size()`

Answer (score 5):

Did you try:

```
ArrayList<String> tmp = h.get("keyOne");
if ( tmp != null ) {
    return tmp.size();
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would make it `return -1` if `null`, to differentiate `null` from empty `ArrayList`s

Answer (score 2):

```
int count = h.get("keyOne").size();
```

should do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Set;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> h = new LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> al1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        al1.add("Value11");
        al1.add("Value12");
        al1.add("Value13");
        ArrayList<String> al2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        al2.add("Value21");
        h.put("key1", al1);
        h.put("key2", null);
        Set<String> set = h.keySet();
        for (String key : set) {
            ArrayList<String> al = h.get(key);
            if (al != null)
                System.out.println (key + " : " + al.size());
            else
                System.out.println (key + " is empty ");
        } 
    }
}
```

Output:

```
key1 : 3
key2 is empty
```

Comment: an existing ArrayList of size zero should probably also print "is empty"

Comment: @Thilo not really, the array would be empty, but the map wouldn't. In my opinion, it needs to print `0`. But that's a matter of taste. Easily fixed with another `if` clause.

Comment: Agree that it is a matter of taste/requirement.